# AlertDialog Layout below the buttons

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-alertdialog

I have my own layout for an AlertDialog, and if I use setPositiveButton everything works. But when i use setItems, my layout is shown below the item buttons.

How can I show my custom layout on top?

Here is my code:

```
       private void selectImage(){
final CharSequence[] items = { TAKE_PICTURE, FROM_GALLERY, CANCLE};
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Add_Object.this);
            LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
            View content =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog, null);
            builder.setView(content);
            ((TextView) content.findViewById(R.id.dialogTitle)).setText(R.string.addPictureTitle);
             builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    if (items[item].equals(TAKE_PICTURE)) {
                            captureImage();
                    } else if (items[item].equals(FROM_GALLERY)) {
                            chooseFromGallery();
                    } else if (items[item].equals(CANCLE)) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });
            builder.show();
        }
    }
```

And my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialogTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="@color/main_color"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/dialogDivider"
        android:layout_below="@id/dialogTitle"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@color/main_color" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialogText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dialogDivider"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@color/darkgrey"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `builder.setCustomTitle(content)` instead of `setView(content)`, but this will add a separator line between your layout and the item buttons...

**EDIT:**
As an alternative, you can add the list to your custom layout, e.g. with an TextView like this:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/take_picture"
    android:layout_below="@id/dialogText"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:textSize="26sp"
    android:onClick="takePicture"/>
```

and define the takePicture method in your MainActivity:

```
public void takePicture(View view) {
    Log.i("MainActivity", "take picture");
    //cancel the dialog
    dialog.dismiss();
}
```

the dialog is saved in a class variable, and initialized in selectImage():

```
private void selectImage(){
    final CharSequence[] items = {  "TAKE_PICTURE", "FROM_GALLERY", "CANCLE"};
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    View title =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog, null);
    builder.setView(title);
    ((TextView) title.findViewById(R.id.dialogTitle)).setText("picture title");
    ((TextView) title.findViewById(R.id.take_picture)).setText(items[0]);
    //init dialog
    dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. My layout is on top but now there is also shown the standard divider before the items.

Comment: yes, I didn't find a solution for this. Maybe this can be solved by changing the theme, don't know